# XERO - Private app not working

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to create a private app by creating a pem file, however, this is not working. I get an error 'Failed to create app'.

Tried using the below ssl commands listed on https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/create-publicprivate-key

openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 1825
openssl pkcs12 -export -out public_privatekey.pfx -inkey privatekey.pem -in publickey.cer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried following the steps in the docs provided and I was able to create a private app.

Can you try logging in and create the private app again? Let me know how it goes.
If it happens again, could you open the web inspector and post the HTTP error you are receiving? Thanks!